# C# Reflection Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#, reflection

I am getting the following error from the C# code below.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T, T2>(this Expression<Func<T, T2>> propertyLambda)
{
    var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression
        ?? ((UnaryExpression)propertyLambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;    
}
```

> System.InvalidCastException  :  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression'

Attached is the front end code in MVC which gets called to this C# code

```
.AddControl(x => x.SipKpiCriteria.Select(y => y.EvaluationMethod).FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: well, a MethodCallExpression *isn't* a UnaryExpression (a UnaryExpression would be things like `! foo` (for some expression foo); what is it that you're trying to do here? what is the expression that you're trying to deconstruct?

Comment: The "method call" here is `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(...)`. What property are you trying to get from that? the `SipKpiCriteria`? the `EvaluationMethod` ? something else? What you're actually calling here is  (presumably, a little hard to tell - could be `Queryable` etc) `x => Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Enumerable.Select(x.SipKpiCriteria, y => y.EvaluationMethod))`

Comment: @MarcGravell, I think that method call expression would actually be `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(...)`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride yes, I realised that and already fixed

Comment: Am still getting the same problem.. trying to get the property Evaluation Method from the  collection Enumerable

Comment: That's non-trivial. You have to crawl through the expression tree to find it. And then it probably will only work for your one example case. Without having all the details/requirements, I think using Expressions is too much of a hazzle in this case. Just create an overload of `AddControl()` that accepts a name `string` and a `Type`.

Comment: Can I get more help from the exception thrown above. there's already a method AddControl() which accepts Tmodel and string.